# Can I set different indentation for different languages in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: pycharm, indentation

According to [Django Coding Style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/), I should use 4-space indentation for Python files and 2-space indentation in HTML. I have enable Django's .editorconfig already, but PyCharm still uses 4 spaces in HTML. Can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that on `Settings > Editor > Code Style`. And set the indentation 4 for `python` and 2 for `html` as it can be seen below:

**Python:**

[image: Python]

**Html:**

[image: Html]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how does it play together with .editorconfig?

Comment: There is a plugin called `EditorConfig`. If you enable this plugin and you have   `.editorconfig` file in your project, the settings defined in the `.editorconfig` will override the Code Style settings of the IDE.

Comment: My .editorconfig (from Django) defines `indent_size = 4` and `[*.html] indent_size = 2`. However PyCharm makes it 4 everywhere, as in settings. That's what puzzled me. But apparently it's just a PyCharm bug in EditorConfig implementation. Thanks for the answers.